# There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" (" </div>

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap, ngx-bootstrap-modal

Tried every thing like removing ModalModule from App.module and others thing but getting same error

> ERROR in : There is no directive with "exportAs" set to "bs-modal" ("
>
> ```
>     <div bsModal [ERROR ->]#lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-sizes-name")
> ```

App.module.ts

```
import { BsDropdownModule, ModalModule, ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

imports: [
    ModalModule.forRoot()]
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
  },
  { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
  { path: '**', loadChildren: 'app/pages/pages.module#PagesModule' },
];
```

pages.module.ts

```
import { ModalModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';


imports: [ModalModule.forRoot()]
```

dashboard.component.ts

```
import { ModalDirective } from 'ngx-bootstrap';
@Component({
  selector: 'ngx-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ["./dashboard.component.scss"]
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild(ModalDirective)
  lgModal: ModalDirective;
```

dashboard.component.html

```
<div bsModal #lgModal="bs-modal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="dialog-sizes-name1">
          <div class="modal-dialog" style="width:50%;">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" (click)="lgModal.hide()">&times;</button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" style="overflow-y: auto;">
                <div class="row right-col">
                  <div style="padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; width: 100%;">
                    <!-- My code here -->
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Try importing  ModalModule  in PagesModule

Comment: already did this as shown above

Comment: Where is your DashboardComponent  declared?

Comment: thats in pages module

Comment: Can you post the whole error message that starts with `There is no directive with "exportAs" set`